# 100vh element spilling over address bar Chrome / Safari

Tags: reactjs, mobile, tailwind-css

I have a React / Tailwind component with a full screen element. On desktop it works as intended however on mobile the address bars of either chrome of safari cause part of the element to be shown underneath it. Giving the impression that the element isn't correctly centered.

I have researched this issue for a while now and have found no solid answer on how to fix it in React.

I have tried various combinations of `height: --webkit-fill-available` `height: 100vh` `height: 100%` ,with `min-height` also, on `HTML, Root, Body` in my main CSS file. Additionally I have tried several different JS functions that calculate the inner height of the document (the height of the document with the address bar excluded.) As well as not using `height: 100vh` on my targeted element and instead using a combination of `height: 100%` and fixed positioning. None of these methods have worked in any way at all.

Im hoping for a more React oriented fix to this issue instead of a plain HTML method.

Please note: `motion.` to anyone unfamiliar is part of Framer Motion and has no effect on the targeted element outside of using Framer properties.

Heres the component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

export default function LoadingScreen() {
    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
      }, [])

    return(
        <motion.div 
            className="fixed z-50 w-full bg-tertiary"
            initial= {{ opacity: 1 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 2.5, ease: 'easeInOut' }} 
        >
            {/* Image container */}
            <motion.div 
                className="flex justify-center items-center"
                initial= {{ opacity: 0 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                transition={{ duration: 1, ease: 'easeInOut' }} 
            >
                <motion.img 
                    src="../Images/icon.png" 
                    className="h-[80px] absolute left-0 right-0 top-[50%] -translate-y-[50%] px-5 mx-auto"
                    initial= {{ opacity: 1 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    transition={{ duration: 1, delay: 1, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
                ></motion.img>

                <motion.img 
                    src="../Images/icon-primary.png" 
                    className="h-[80px] absolute left-0 right-0 top-[50%] -translate-y-[50%] px-5 mx-auto"
                    initial= {{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    transition={{ duration: 1, delay: 1.5, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
                ></motion.img>
            </motion.div>
        </motion.div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of the result you're looking for?
If you want to make it center both horizontally and vertically, you need to  add the device height in the outer layer so it has the space to center.

```
<motion.div
    className="bg-tertiary fixed z-50 h-screen w-full"
    initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
    transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 2.5, ease: "easeInOut" }}
  >
    {/* Image container */}
    <motion.div
      className="flex items-center justify-center"
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1, ease: "easeInOut" }}
    >
      <motion.img
        src="../Images/icon.png"
        className="absolute left-0 right-0 top-[50%] mx-auto h-[80px] -translate-y-[50%] px-5"
        initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1, delay: 1, ease: "easeInOut" }}
      ></motion.img>

      <motion.img
        src="../Images/icon.png"
        className="absolute left-0 right-0 top-[50%] mx-auto h-[80px] -translate-y-[50%] px-5"
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1, delay: 1.5, ease: "easeInOut" }}
      ></motion.img>
    </motion.div>
  </motion.div>
```